# error TS2339: Property '{}' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicClassAttributes...'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jenkins, error-handling

Hi guys I have a problem with somekind of typescript errors, can you buy me sometime and figure it out? Error lines are marked with //->>//

> *TS2339: Property 'isOccupied' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<RoomStatusProps,any> &
> HTMLProps<H...'.*

code

```
    export class RoomCard extends React.Component<RoomCardProps> {
        render(): JSX.Element {
            const { name, level, isOccupied, currentBooking } = this.props;
    
            const reservationEntries = this.props.reservations
                .filter(entry => {
                    const time = moment.utc().utcOffset(new Date().getTimezoneOffset(), true);
                    const startTime = moment.utc(entry.start);
                    return time.isBefore(startTime) && time.isSame(startTime, 'day');
                })
                .map(entry => <ReservationEntry entry={entry} key={entry.id} />);
    
            return (
   //This line ->// <RoomWrapper isOccupied={isOccupied}>
                    <RoomInfo>
                        <Name>{name}</Name>
                        <Level>Level: {level}</Level>
                    </RoomInfo>
   //This line ->// <Status isOccupied={isOccupied}>
                        Room is currently {isOccupied ? `booked` : 'free'}
                    </Status>
                    {isOccupied && <ReservationEntry entry={currentBooking[0]} />}
                    {!!reservationEntries.length && (
                        <ReservationsHeader>Upcoming reservations:</ReservationsHeader>
                    )}
                    <ReservationsWrapper>{reservationEntries}</ReservationsWrapper>
                </RoomWrapper>
            );
        }
    }
```

Room wrapper and status in glamorous, and I want to add that this project is on 2.4.2 version of typescript:

```
interface RoomCardProps {
    name: string;
    level: number;
    reservations: AssignedReservation[];
    currentBooking: AssignedReservation[];
    isOccupied: boolean;
}

interface RoomStatusProps {
    isOccupied: boolean;
    theme: object;
}

const RoomWrapper = glamorous.div<RoomStatusProps>(
    {
        width: 380,
        borderRadius: 5,
        paddingTop: 10,
        fontSize: fonts.small,
        margin: 10,
    },
    ({ isOccupied = false }) => ({
        border: `2px solid ${isOccupied ? contextColors.notAvailable : contextColors.available}`,
    }),
);

const RoomInfo = glamorous.div({
    width: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    paddingLeft: 10,
});

const Name = glamorous.p({
    marginBottom: 2,
    fontSize: fonts.large,
});

const Level = glamorous.p({
    color: colors.dustyGray,
});

const Status = glamorous.p<RoomStatusProps>(({ isOccupied = false }) => ({
    color: isOccupied ? contextColors.notAvailable : contextColors.available,
    paddingLeft: 10,
}));

const ReservationsHeader = glamorous.p({
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingBottom: 5,
});

const ReservationsWrapper = glamorous.ul({
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    [' :nth-child(2n)']: {
        background: colors.dustyGray,
    },
});
```

[It's all which is related to that problem](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=82&ssc=26&pln=82&pc=50#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAcwDYEMTQgVwM5wGZQQhwDkyaGOJA3AFCiSxwBUcKuASgKYoDG8BIqSg9%20NeuGjxW7OOhBcAdgMLES8pTHETG8AN5xeEJNGwAafBGXnDVmFwAeMAMLHTcAL75VpbFF4A9NgwAJ5IXNjaDFJwBtzYXFAAbigwwFYAospQIRYAgtjYwAiKXAAm8YkpaVae3kIkAHQBlcmp6YpZMDlRyol4fFxwHBBEzihQZQAKhGC4erRwS3CKaFwAXHDBUMCKCHTLcOFJXEibipggAEaJB8siCW01itibBUUl5a3VHQDaALp3Ja8TBQETKABCowA1rsEG9CsVShUIlV2lYAUC4MBsAB5XggsDAcqbK6jcIoRR0Dy0eh9KADXhDEZEADKMFSOBmEDmsUWyxx%20MJxLKpPJPCp-KWMAAFlwFJsIFcAFZcfjU2lGF7wFkgADqUBQYDAiTgAF5EKh0IQcI0ysAkgAeXXsznYblzAB8AAopXzDocAO7AMqyzYAZgAHAAGMx%20w5kyaJDgoe04TYAVjjAeWYFT9r2ABUeZsAIyx%20PLPB2VnAABeG0s1ka2BAKCQSGzObkEwQuzLFcOHi7S29BkFBMwRPK5vw7YSngAlObPXAx5WlomyolNgADABMYAcW2MIbgABI9BPhTOAPy2PpOVwmKDYRqKCAwPIpYCoK7hOBNi1ewnzcV9GhQH8-3CDxdxHJc40XOhaC1YJhlGEAAElFGrWdyGtLA33tJJ1yDEMw1IctowAUhIeD7WwMBUBCTYSDwcIHDov12McAARYARH4DpWKMJBLkULjDjzMoCwQAAZLg8BgAc4w8JDNSsNCADk1jwq1KDfMBSOWNsoD7RQoRgGAiE2fd4OrZRawbTYHJgN9UDMrhVPUlDNPgBSTiQPSKBtQzjOBMCgLAoicFCABxQ1cloNTkNQ%20BXRgHBgoI20wGdDCMq5WZsB9MdsTxSdpzKWcBiQBc1JXNcFkOUToE2a8pxFOB72AxwXGi99P2-FBfxQf8hiix9%20pfN9IJG6CvL9aTZIUpSVOSxcfLS4ZUSeDpsAACR4bcoGygzGiM5rc3zOFizAWzB2umS4VW5S4HLeDlrhSzrJATNvNSvydseH5NINI0TVOi18POzAkHCuAGKYlAWNIHjOPsjj%20ME54ROMcTJOWX4SEA5QZQAWl4GVfzKb190URcSH%20TYrpzK4%20GhBAbUUUVbBmu1YpCBKUfg4cNroRxdEMVBCnQsYJmqvqlDKThRBgRpXEkUplHy%20XJg9Er-XuZXEm9RdNgAKVZAANRoMnCBRlCNnNtoMVYFAsY5TgsDqqosEEwU0KEIFhPY6gtWUcQu4rkO7B80IeNFni6HYIlnSPDOKxpE72zSNwDRo8F-ewoG9TQcka1m44Dba0gUWcNGURpMBgXgzeb1vcTwPAEhgb1SkDOBeNSLh24QLgYELUAuDrKwuC7nuJ7NixukwLh1Or7ttuCCZJ%20nhuiE0Du2-LkIWw5WAN83gMREyqBFDgOuuEaHEIUU6BR532Ap4UZcADI-6P2ni-bArI1jei-nvD2pAygoxIFfTeal86HEaG2Iyp9GrOl2qDTo2QQhwFPmaPQp8vDQi4CEIhp8X5lC8AET0Pk4631BA-X0184C631IaY0ppfYiiIbw8oHhPTIO7Bw7C1ZhFsLjo6HSChPR6HdlwDwjoAiyK4JIqROZHQBVOJ6HRZxYheyQMogI%20iNGaJUbqcREBzFSMdIVXAAiyj8IqjeGhtjNFLF1OVQwoJwQwCQPgq8rjOp3jgLuMkIdyi7kAmjEQXASA0k8ewgIDiPHX2CUKUJ1UAHsO%20OiXB3R8GEL0AHfxwdQ4IF%20NGf4tDPRJM8XoAAhE0nOOCU7EnckoBAso4C5NYck5YWCQYFMOsdRInoACqYAjAgDhHANpoz1iWOwaMo6qYJkiJzIuBpFj8nPGwODbhUB5GLOTtkTpJj9n7SOZDdJWiWgYVuZsuOCDPDJVoEAA)

**By the way the problem is only with `<RoomWrapper isOccupied={isOccupied}>`**

Comment: please don't use pictures in your questions. share reproducable example in ts playground and comment the line with error

Comment: Okey changed that :)

Comment: share RoomWrapper and Status components

Comment: I've added that above, it's made with glamorous styling dependency

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChRJY4BzAGxRGggFcBnObXAuhpts8gDsYSKJnRJEEXAGUYKGGwAKOMOwDepONrjBWAeTRpmYYEgAmALjgAjabVSCA3KQC+pUmgiDW8BNJAAdSgUMDBROABeGnpGHDYAOnNgADcAHn9ZeUVWFQg1AD4ACi0dTR0KuAB3YHMYAAtrAGYADgAGABpSyttoc1EEFGS2awBWLp7tMCHkwWoAFXzrAEZO7sqQFChqYEEVtYrXCZ0i9V0DIxMzcyiOFFpWSVcASiiCuFP1irsofqhrAAGACYwAAPOCsCC0WpwAAk6j0hmMpgscAA-AQiOZ8HBrPgbPQ0ABrfCuAHHbQvLrPFyeby+OAAMWktyKr0i7wyAWCoXCUHOSKuFki6hgUGYSFccAA9AUgA

Comment: Please check above link, it works

Comment: I've checked that and I really appreciate that but when I removed theme object from interface consol is giving me somekind of host error, but what about the foo? how can I wrap it there ? :)

Comment: Please share fully reprodycable example. You still did not share AssignedReservation, colors, contextColors etc ...

Comment: Okey my friend I have added couple of files to the post ;))

Comment: Please put it all into one file and try to remove redundant code. share minimum reproducable example. In fact, we dont need all these files. we need to reproduce your error

Comment: Just look at that file, maybe I have to declare it in custom.d.ts ? to walkaround and prevent showing that problem

Comment: Okey I've realized that making interface RoomStatusProps {
    isOccupied: boolean;
    theme?: object;
}
solved the problem! Thanks